# Database interface with RYU controller

Tags: database, ip, sdn, ryu

Is it possible to interface a database containing IP address with RYU controller where the incoming packet IP address is compared and a result is sent to the controller as true or false?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a Python package called NetworkX which will store the network topology as a graph and store all of the devices as nodes in that graph then you can get any information about the network such as a host IP.

https://networkx.github.io/